# Store 2d matrix in CSV: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I wrote the following function for calculating cost matrix and storing it in CSV file:

```
private static void calculateCostMatrix()
{
    int len = _POIs.size();
    CostMatrix = new double[len][len];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        int ic = _POIs.get(i).getId();
        for (int j=i; j<len; j++)
        {
            int jc = _POIs.get(j).getId();
            double dist = euclideandist(_POIs.get(i).getLat(),_POIs.get(i).getLon(),
                                    _POIs.get(j).getLat(),_POIs.get(j).getLon());
            CostMatrix[ic][jc] = dist;
            CostMatrix[jc][ic] = dist;
        }           
    }

    // Save in CSV
    try
    {
        String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        File file = new File("CostMatrix.csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()); 
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();;
        for (double[] row : CostMatrix) 
        {
            for (double d : row)
            {
                 sb.append(d);
                 sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(NEW_LINE);
        }
        bw.write(sb.toString());
        bw.close();
        }

        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, obviously, due to large number of elements (200,000 x 200,000) I get the message `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

So, instead of pre-allocating a space for CostMAtrix, I now want to directly calculate and store each cell in CSV file.
How can I do this in the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it differently. Since the problem is memory, you could use a temporary binary file on disk instead of an array to store the result. Create this temporary files of the right size, then seek through it to store the double results (in binary form).

Once you are done processing the whole matrix in binary, parse the file to convert it to CSV.

Otherwise, you'll have to sort your POIs by value and keep their index as a reference for the CSV row/column loop.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a link to some example? Also, I will need to use CostMatrix in my iterative calculations. So, it means that after calculating CostMatrix and storing it in CSV, I will need to somehow load this file to be able to access CostMAtrix[i][j] from my dynamic algorithm.

Comment: Accessing a CSV file as a random access is very slow and difficult by nature. You should maybe consider the binary file as a final result and work on this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: Ok. I am also evaluating NEO4j, but I'm not sure.. http://neo4j.com/developer/get-started/